# Unpack hex-encoded binary data in PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex, iot

We're collecting data from a partner's IoT devices and the data comes encoded in a hex string like `1C000000010028` which contains binary data:

- Byte 0 bit 0 Boolean
- Byte 0 bit 1 Boolean
- Byte 0 bit 2 Boolean
- Byte 0 bit 3 Boolean
- Byte 0 bits 4-7 UInt4
- Bytes 1-2 bits 0-15 UInt16
- Byte 3 bits 0-7 UInt8
- Bytes 4-5 bits 0-15 UInt16
- Byte 6 bits 0-7 UInt8

I have never worked with this kind of data and am wondering how to decode / unpack this in PHP. I was guessing that https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.unpack.php would be my friend but I just don't get it. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Additional info: Indexing: bytes are in big-endian order and bits in standard 76543210 "little endian" order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They say that the input is a hex string like '1C000000010028'.

```
$code = '1C000000010028';
```

To use unpack() the data must be a string with binaryData. You can convert it with hex2bin.

```
$binaryData = hex2bin($code);
// "\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x28"
```

Now you could use unpack.

```
$arr = unpack('Cbyte_0/vUInt16_0/Cbyte_1/vUInt16_1/Cbyte_2',$binaryData);
/*
$arr = array (
  'byte_0' => 28,
  'UInt16_0' => 0,
  'byte_1' => 0,
  'UInt16_1' => 1,
  'byte_2' => 40,
)
*/
```

Individual data types such as Boolean and UInt4 are not included in the pack/unpack formats. To get this data you have to work with the [bit operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Just one example of this:

```
$byte_0bit2 = (bool)($arr['byte_0'] & 0b00000100);
```

This can lead to further questions, the answers of which can be found here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration @jspit! I also found a footnote in the manual: "Indexing: bytes are in big-endian order and bits in standard 76543210 "little endian" order." to make it even more fun...

My current solution is a bit weird, but works:

`str_split(str_pad(base_convert($message, 16, 2), 56, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), 8);`

Then something like

`$part[0] = (bool)$bytes[0][7];`

`$part[4] = bindec(substr($bytes[0], 0, 4));`

etc...